# ASp.net WCF in Vs 2010

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have class file with many properties such as  First Name, Last Name, Phone Number. I got this properties in object. Now how to convert this object into list object?

Comment: code please - otherwise its really difficult to understand what you're getting at

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
List<classname> name = new List<classname>();
```